# Как сделать отступы у блоков с помощью nth-child

Tags: css, css3, псевдоэлемент

Задание:

Установите отступ слева и справа по `30px` для элементов с классом `.card`, начиная со 2го элемента и далее через каждые 3 элемента (то есть, для 2го, 5го и т.д.)

Я пытался сделать отступы через `nth-child` и `nth-of-type`, но это не работает.

https://codepen.io/realHikkan/pen/ZEORrGa?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

работает. Просто вы пропустили точку на 17й строке

У вас:

```
card:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Надо:

```
.card:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

все работает, просто

```
.card:nth-child(1n+4) {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

card:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

в классе забыта `card` точка

```css
.parent {
    margin: 10px;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 15px;
    
    background: red;
}

.child:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'parent'>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
    <div class = 'child'></div>
</div>
```